# The correct syntax for if...elif...else in Bash

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement

I'm a beginner when it comes to shell scripts, and learning it in college FOSS lab. I have seen two different syntax for the if statement, and both are working, so am not sure what is the right one that I should stick into.

```
if [ condition ]
then
    # statements
else
    # statements
fi
```

This was the one I found in our class books, and it is indeed working in bash. The next syntax I found online was with an extra `;` symbol, like this.

```
if [ condition ]; then
    # statements
else
    # statements
fi
```

What is the difference between the two? And which is the good practice to stick to?

Comment: to write two sepearte stmts in a single line.

Comment: like `if [ condition ]; then stmt1; else stmt 2; fi`

Comment: Semicolon is a command separator, you can write any number of statements on a single line if you separate them with semicolons. `cd /tmp; ls -lah; echo "foo"; touch bar`

Comment: Same syntax, different command terminators

Comment: Thanks for the replies, but one of the questions is still there, which is recommended?

Comment: Someone with 5k rep should know that opinion-based questions are not on topic for the site.

Comment: @miken32 I know that it is indeed off topic, but am asking since I want to keep myself to a standard convention and don't know which is better to follow. Sorry about that.

Comment: I can't find any empirical studies showing that one is better than the other, but I imagine that if one was clearly better we'd know by now.

Comment: Adopt some standard, such as https://google.github.io/styleguide/shell.xml

Comment: It's basically *K&R syntax* vs. *Allman syntax*